# Why does pattern matching against &Option<_> give a reference to the wrapped value?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

Suppose I have the following code:

```rust
fn print_type_of<T>(msg: &str, _: &T) {
    println!("type of {}: {}", msg, std::any::type_name::<T>())
}

fn main() {
    let x: &Option<i32> = &Some(32);
    match x {
        Some(y) => print_type_of("y", &y),
        None => println!("None"),
    };
}
```

[link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5acae3ca3c19a12c19794771bf3c3f36)

Could you explain why the program prints: `type of y: &i32`? Why does pattern matching against `&Option<_>` give a reference to the wrapped value rather than the value itself?

Comment: What would you expect it to return other than a reference?

Comment: No, I want to understand why a reference is returned